# Dark artifacts in mathematica plot

Tags: plotting

When plotting in *Mathematica* I just got some "dark artifacts". Here is my code:

```
Plot3D[Exp[-100 x^2], {x, -5, 5}, {p, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> {100, 100}]
```

and the result is[image]

(I know that the `3D` is useless here, but I minimized my actual code to the relevant problem).
I have the feeling that it has something to do with the precision, when there is the transition from `10^-200` or so to `0` but increasing the `WorkingPrecision` didn't change anything.
I tried plotting in `2D` from `x = 2.3` and there is still an exponential function with value `10^-175` to see. When I plot from `3` to `4` (which is after the dark artifact line) then the `2D` `Plot` says just zero.

I don't need to caluculate with super high precision, I just want to get rid of those dark strips.
I also tried to look for similar questions but couldnt find one, perhaps because I don't really know if artifacts is the right word.

Comment: it's just fp noise. Try plotting `Chop@Exp[-100 x^2]` to get rid of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Chop` is useful here:

You can use it inside the `Plot3D` (as rm -rf wrote in the comment) for rounding small values of `Exp`

```
Plot3D[Chop@Exp[-100 x^2], {x, -5, 5}, {p, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

If your function is complicated you can use `Chop` as the post-processing function

```
Chop@Plot3D[Exp[-100 x^2], {x, -5, 5}, {p, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

In the both cases results are the same:

[image]

Comment: thx to you, ybeltukov, and rm -rf. i appreciate the post-processing option :)